# Json from python to php 5.3

Tags: php, python, json

I am trying to pass a dictionary that has been jsoned from python to php, but the json_decode function cant decode it.
I tried decoding it online [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/) and it worked fine.

this is a sample of the json data.. its kinda big.. sorry.

```
{"Scientists Extend Einstein&#39;s Relativity to the Universe&#39;s First Moments. January 9  . Fairly Simple Math Could Bridge Quantum Mechanics and General Relativity.": {"39": 4, "9": 3, "Universe&#": 4, "Extend": 2, "fairli": 2, "Could": 3, "Bridg": 3, "Moment": 2, ".": 1, "to": 3, "s": 2, "scientist": 3, "Rel": 3, "Einstein&#": 2, "januari": 2, ";": 1, "Simpl": 3, "the": 4, "Math": 3, "First": 2}, "Real Time Relativity is a computer program running on Windows or Mac OSX  systems that allows the user to interactively experience a virtual relativistic world.": {"comput": 7, "is": 5, "Window": 9, "Rel": 5, "OSX": 9, "interact": 6, "system": 9, "virtual": 7, ".": 1, "to": 4, "Mac": 9, "program": 7, "experi": 5, "real": 3, "run": 7, "that": 4, "relativist": 6, "user": 6, "Time": 5, "world": 6, "a": 7, "on": 8, "allow": 5, "the": 6, "or": 9}, "The Relativity of Wrong By Isaac Asimov. I RECEIVED a letter the other day. It  was handwritten in crabbed penmanship so that it was very difficult to read.": {"it": 5, "Rel": 3, "in": 3, "Isaac": 4, "RECEIV": 3, "Asimov": 4, ".": 4, "to": 6, "Wrong": 5, "other": 4, "crab": 4, "penmanship": 4, "By": 5, "handwritten": 2, "wa": 5, "that": 3, "I": 3, "letter": 5, "veri": 5, "day": 4, "a": 5, "read": 7, "of": 3, "so": 3, "the": 4, "difficult": 6}, "Relativity School will be a new degree based Film and Performing Arts School  opening in August 2014. Created by Relativity Media, students will have gain .": {"and": 4, "have": 4, "creat": 1, "Perform": 4, "Media": 4, "Rel": 4, "in": 4, "open": 4, "August": 5, ",": 3, ".": 3, "rel": 3, "2014": 5, "gain ": 5, "be": 3, "School": 4, "base": 3, "student": 4, "new": 4, "by": 2, "a": 4, "Art": 4, "will": 4, "degre": 4, "Film": 4}, "The latest from Relativity Media (@relativitymedia). Passionate people with the  freedom to create and a platform to share their talents with the world.": {"and": 6, "@": 6, "from": 3, "creat": 4, "platform": 6, ")": 5, "Media": 5, "freedom": 6, ".": 1, "to": 3, "passion": 2, "a": 6, "Rel": 5, "(": 5, "relativitymedia": 6, "world": 7, "the": 7, "with": 6, "peopl": 5, "latest": 3}, "Relativity Fest is kCura&#39;s annual user conference, designed to give its user  community a great Relativity educational experience.": {"give": 5, "is": 3, "it": 7, "design": 3, "Rel": 6, "commun": 7, ",": 1, ".": 2, "to": 4, "Fest": 3, "rel": 3, ";": 4, "experi": 6, "great": 6, "confer": 4, "user": 7, "educ": 6, "a": 6, "39": 4, "annual": 4, "s": 4, "kCura&#": 3}, "Online publication of the 1920 edition of Albert Einstein&#39;s Relativity.": {"1920": 5, "Rel": 6, "onlin": 2, "the": 5, "39": 6, "edit": 5, "of": 5, "Albert": 6, ".": 1, "s": 6, "Einstein&#": 6, ";": 6, "public": 2}, " Prev · Random · Next  · . Permanent link to this comic: http://xkcd.com/1233/  Image URL (for hotlinking/embedding): http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/relativity.png.": {"//imgs.xkcd.com/comics/relativity.png": 4, ":": 6, "http": 6, "thi": 4, "to": 3, "URL": 7, "Imag": 7, "Random": 3, "//xkcd.com/1233/": 7, "Next": 3, ".": 1, "link": 2, "perman": 2, "·": 3, "comic": 5, "prev": 2}, "A text book tutorial on the modern physics of Albert Einstein&#39;s theories of special  relativity and general relativity.": {"A": 3, "on": 5, "39": 5, "special": 4, "tutori": 5, "text": 3, "gener": 2, "modern": 6, "Albert": 5, "and": 2, "s": 3, "book": 5, "theori": 3, "rel": 2, "of": 3, "Einstein&#": 5, "the": 6, ";": 1, "physic": 6}, "RELATIVITY GOES TURBO!: Relativity Music will be releasing the DreamWorks  Animation film soundtrack to TURBO. Track listin read more. May 2, 2013.": {"REL": 3, "Music": 3, "Rel": 3, "film": 4, "!": 2, "TURBO": 4, "Anim": 4, "DreamWork": 5, ",": 2, ".": 1, "GOE": 4, "2": 3, ":": 2, "2013": 3, "more": 2, "be": 3, "may": 2, "soundtrack": 4, "track": 2, "releas": 3, "listin": 2, "read": 2, "will": 3, "the": 5}, "Relativity Media - Filmography. Join IMDb Pro for more details!": {"Media": 3, "!": 1, "Filmographi": 4, "join": 2, "for": 4, "Pro": 4, "-": 3, "detail": 5, ".": 1, "IMDb": 4, "rel": 2, "more": 5}, "Index · HyperPhysics. R Nave. Go Back.": {"index": 3, "HyperPhys": 3, "Nave": 2, "·": 3, "go": 2, "R": 2, "Back": 3, ".": 1}, "This is a marker sentence.": {"a": 3, "sentenc": 3, "is": 2, ".": 1, "thi": 2, "marker": 3}, "rel·a·tiv·i·ty n. 1. The quality or state of being relative. 2. A state of dependence in  which the existence or significance of one entity is solely dependent on that of .": {"A": 2, "be": 4, "which": 6, "that": 8, "is": 6, "sole": 7, "qualiti": 2, "one": 8, "signific": 7, "exist": 6, "in": 5, "The": 2, ".": 5, "the": 6, "entiti": 8, "on": 7, "of ": 8, "depend": 6, "rel·a·tiv·i·ti": 2, "of": 7, "n": 2, "state": 2, "rel": 4, "2.": 2, "or": 5, "1.": 2}, "A peer-refereed, solely online physics journal publishing invited reviews covering  all areas of relativity research. Published by the Max Planck Institute for .": {"all": 4, "Institut": 4, "for ": 4, "onlin": 2, ".": 1, "peer-refere": 2, "area": 4, "Max": 5, "review": 2, ",": 1, "publish": 2, "research": 5, "rel": 5, "A": 2, "journal": 2, "sole": 2, "by": 3, "physic": 2, "invit": 2, "of": 4, "cover": 2, "the": 5, "Planck": 5}, "In this course, you will gain an understanding of these discoveries through a  focus on relativityEinstein&#39;s fascinating and non-intuitive description of the .": {"and": 4, "relativityEinstein&#": 9, "an": 7, "through": 6, "in": 1, ".": 2, "cours": 4, ",": 3, "discoveri": 8, "fascin": 3, "you": 4, "understand": 7, "gain": 4, ";": 2, "a": 8, "on": 8, "39": 9, "these": 8, "of": 7, "descript": 4, "focu": 8, "will": 4, "s": 3, "thi": 4, "non-intuit": 4}, "4 Sep 2009 . Relativity can be described using space-time diagrams. Contrary to popular  opinion, Einstein did not invent relativity. Galileo preceded him.": {"invent": 4, "galileo": 2, "use": 5, "describ": 4, ",": 5, ".": 1, "to": 3, "4": 2, "rel": 5, "be": 4, "diagram": 6, "not": 4, "him": 4, "contrari": 2, "space-tim": 6, "Sep": 2, "did": 4, "preced": 3, "can": 3, "Einstein": 6, "popular": 6, "opinion": 6, "2009": 3}, "General relativity is a theory of gravitation and to understand the background to  the theory we have to look at how theories of gravitation developed. Aristotle&#39;s .": {"and": 8, "is": 2, "at": 8, "have": 4, "develop": 9, "to": 5, ".": 1, "how": 9, "rel": 2, "gravit": 10, "Aristotle&#": 2, ";": 2, "s ": 2, "we": 4, "gener": 2, "understand": 9, "theori": 9, "background": 10, "a": 6, "39": 2, "look": 6, "of": 10, "the": 6}, "Journal published by Springer, devoted to articles on general relativity and its  applications.": {"and": 7, "applic": 7, "Springer": 5, "devot": 3, "gener": 8, "it": 7, ".": 2, "by": 4, "on": 6, ",": 1, "publish": 3, "articl": 5, "to": 4, "rel": 8, "journal": 3}, "OLDER VERSIONS. MOD. This mod&#39;s purview is the manipulation of interaction  tuning and the alteration of how time flows in the game. DOCUMENTATION.": {"and": 7, "purview": 2, "39": 2, "OLDER": 2, "of": 4, "is": 2, "manipul": 4, "alter": 7, ".": 1, "mod&#": 3, "s": 2, "VERSION": 2, "interact": 5, "thi": 3, ";": 2, "DOCUMENT": 1, "the": 7, "tune": 6, "MOD": 1}, "A fascinating article that helps you to understand the basics of special relativity!  Learn how special relativity works with this HowStuffWorks.com article.": {"A": 3, "!": 1, "HowStuffWorks.com": 4, "work": 2, "thi": 4, "help": 4, "that": 3, "of": 3, "learn": 2, "how": 3, "articl": 4, "to": 3, "fascin": 3, "understand": 4, "rel": 2, "basic": 4, "you": 2, ".": 1, "with": 3, "the": 4, "special": 3}, "Romantic and family serio-comic drama series about two American strangers in  their twenties who meet and fall in love in Italy, and return home, get to know .": {"and": 3, "love": 7, "know ": 6, "fall": 4, ",": 3, "Itali": 8, "famili": 2, "in": 7, "home": 4, "to": 5, "two": 5, ".": 3, "their": 4, "twenti": 4, "return": 4, "get": 4, "who": 3, "American": 5, "serio-com": 2, "romant": 3, "about": 4, "stranger": 5, "drama": 4, "meet": 4, "seri": 4}, "Albert Einstein&#39;s Theory of Relativity. In Words of Four Letters or Less. [ 0 ]. So,  have a seat. Put your feet up. This may take some time. Can I get you some tea?": {"Word": 4, "have": 3, "up": 3, "may": 2, "thi": 2, "albert": 2, "some": 5, "seat": 4, "feet": 3, "you": 5, "Rel": 5, "in": 3, "put": 2, "[": 2, "]": 2, "your": 3, "a": 4, "39": 4, "I": 2, "Less": 4, "of": 3, "get": 2, ",": 2, "can": 1, ".": 1, "Four": 5, "0": 2, "s": 4, "so": 1, "Theori": 4, "Letter": 5, "time": 3, "Einstein&#": 2, ";": 4, "tea": 5, "or": 4, "?": 3, "take": 2}, "Albert Einstein&#39;s first paper on relativity, translated here from Annalen der Physik  vol XVII 1905 p. 891-921, is of historical interest.": {"vol": 5, "is": 2, "paper": 2, "1905": 4, "Annalen": 5, "from": 3, ",": 2, ".": 1, "Physik": 5, "Einstein&#": 2, ";": 2, "interest": 4, "albert": 2, "here": 4, "translat": 2, "39": 2, "of": 3, "der": 5, "histor": 4, "p": 4, "s": 2, "XVII": 5, "891-921": 3, "first": 2}, "Escher&#39;s \"Relativity\" in LEGO. Because The LEGO Company get paranoid  about this sort of thing let me make it clear that I have no affiliation with them, that  my .": {"sort": 7, "``": 1, "have": 16, "get": 3, "I": 16, "becaus": 1, "it": 13, "''": 3, "let": 9, "no": 18, "Rel": 3, "in": 3, "my ": 7, "The": 3, "with": 18, "Compani": 3, "me": 11, "affili": 18, "39": 3, "them": 19, "Escher&#": 2, "LEGO": 3, "paranoid": 3, "of": 7, "make": 11, "that": 6, ",": 8, ".": 2, "thing": 8, "s": 2, "thi": 7, "about": 4, ";": 2, "clear": 14}, "Highly recommendable collection of interconnected web pages that serve as an  informal introduction to general relativity. While some mathematics is used, the .": {"is": 3, "some": 3, "the ": 5, "highli": 2, "web": 3, "use": 3, "interconnect": 3, "of": 2, ",": 4, ".": 2, "collect": 1, "while": 1, "mathemat": 3, "recommend": 2, "page": 3}, "Introduction to relativity, why it doesn&#39;t like faster-than-light speeds, and what  might theoretically be done about it. Includes section on physics and Star Trek.": {"and": 6, "it": 6, "done": 4, "faster-than-light": 7, "speed": 7, "what": 3, "Star": 6, "to": 2, "section": 2, ",": 1, "theoret": 5, ".": 4, "doesn&#": 4, "includ": 1, "rel": 3, ";": 5, "might": 4, "be": 4, "Trek": 6, "whi": 3, "physic": 5, "introduct": 1, "on": 3, "39": 5, "like": 6, "t": 6, "about": 5}, "17 Oct 2013 . The theory of relativity explains that the time and position of an event is relative to  the frame of reference of an observer. This prezi simplifies the .": {"and": 3, "simplifi": 3, "thi": 3, "that": 3, "is": 2, "an": 9, "theori": 4, "observ": 9, "the ": 3, "Oct": 2, "17": 2, "of": 8, "explain": 5, "event": 4, ".": 1, "to": 4, "prezi": 3, "rel": 3, "time": 4, "posit": 3, "the": 6, "frame": 6, "2013": 3, "refer": 8}, "Relativity is a Corporate Communications Boutique specialising in Video  Production and Rich Media Presentations. We cater to clients from corporate, .": {"a": 3, " ": 8, "we": 3, "from": 6, "Commun": 3, "Corpor": 3, "is": 2, ",": 7, ".": 1, "to": 4, "client": 6, "cater": 3, "rel": 2, "corpor": 7, "Boutiqu": 3}, "Albert Einstein Reference Archive. Relativity. The Special and General Theory .  Incompatability of the Law of Propagation of Light with the Principle of Relativity": {"and": 2, "albert": 2, "Refer": 3, "Gener": 2, ".": 1, "Archiv": 3, "Theori": 2, "rel": 1, "Einstein": 3, "the": 2, "Special": 2}, "Be Rock Solid: Tens of thousands rely on Relativity for review. Go Faster: Turbo- charge your review workflow. Do More: Tackle problems beyond review.": {"do": 2, "Tackl": 4, "Rel": 7, "go": 2, "beyond": 3, "More": 4, "for": 4, "review": 3, ".": 1, "reli": 7, ":": 4, "be": 2, "Faster": 3, "Turbo-": 3, "Solid": 4, "thousand": 6, "Rock": 4, "charg": 3, "on": 6, "Ten": 3, "of": 4, "problem": 4}, "Then Albert Einstein shook the foundations of physics with the introduction of his  Special Theory of Relativity in 1905, and his General Theory of Relativity in .": {"and": 2, "then": 2, "1905": 6, "in": 5, "in ": 5, "foundat": 8, "Gener": 4, "of": 4, "Albert": 3, "Theori": 4, ",": 2, ".": 2, "hi": 4, "Special": 8, "Rel": 5, "Einstein": 3, "the": 11, "introduct": 11, "with": 10, "physic": 10, "shook": 3}, "The research of the numerical relativity group at the AEI focuses on the study of  the physics and astrophysics of black holes and neutron stars, whose accurate .": {"and": 3, "whose": 2, ",": 1, "group": 5, "numer": 6, "of": 4, "focus": 7, "research": 5, "astrophys": 4, "black": 5, "at": 5, "rel": 5, "neutron": 3, "AEI": 7, "star": 3, "the": 8, "accurate ": 2, ".": 1, "hole": 5, "physic": 8}, "The International Society on General Relativity and Gravitation, ISGRG, is an  international learned society. It acts as Affiliated Commission 2 (AC.2) of the .": {"and": 5, "Affili": 6, "societi": 3, "is": 2, "it": 3, "an": 3, "intern": 3, "Rel": 5, "Gravit": 5, "Gener": 5, ",": 1, ".": 1, "2": 6, "on": 3, "act": 3, "the ": 7, "Societi": 3, "of": 6, "as": 4, "ISGRG": 4, "Intern": 3, "learn": 3, "the": 3, "Commiss": 6}, "28 Jul 2010 - 9 min - Uploaded by ScienceTVhttp://facebook.com/ScienceReason . Albert Einstein&#39;s Theory of Relativity ( Chapter 1 .": {"28": 2, "ScienceTVhttp": 3, "Rel": 5, "min": 2, "(": 5, "-": 1, "Jul": 2, ".": 1, "1": 5, "Theori": 4, "9": 2, ";": 4, ":": 1, "2010": 2, "Chapter": 5, "albert": 2, "Upload": 2, "Einstein&#": 2, "by": 2, "39": 4, "of": 4, "s": 4, "//facebook.com/ScienceReason": 3}, "18 Sep 2012 . This was the theory of special relativity. It introduced a new framework for all of  physics and proposed new concepts of space and time. Einstein .": {"and": 8, "all": 5, "concept": 10, "rel": 4, "wa": 2, "time": 8, "it": 2, "framework": 3, "Einstein ": 1, "theori": 3, "special": 4, "a": 3, "for": 3, "Sep": 2, "18": 2, "space": 11, ".": 1, "physic": 7, "thi": 2, "of": 10, "new": 10, "the": 3, "propos": 7, "introduc": 2, "2012": 3}, "Rank · Movie Title (click to view) · Studio · Total Gross / Theaters .": {"Gross": 4, "Movi": 3, ")": 3, "Titl": 3, "Theaters ": 2, "rank": 3, ".": 1, "to": 5, "Studio": 3, "/": 2, "·": 3, "(": 3, "Total": 4, "click": 5, "view": 6}, "Relativity, also known as Relativity Records, is a US label with many logos.  Although it was reportedly established in 1985 by Barry Kobrin at the site of his .": {"although": 1, "is": 3, "it": 3, "Kobrin": 6, "as": 4, "at": 6, "Rel": 5, "in": 4, "Barri": 6, ".": 2, "establish": 3, "1985": 5, ",": 1, "label": 4, "also": 3, "rel": 3, "wa": 3, "site": 8, "Record": 5, "reportedli": 4, "known": 3, "by": 4, "a": 4, "his ": 9, "of": 8, "US": 4, "the": 8}, "Relativity: The Special and General Theory [Albert Einstein, Robert W. Lawson]  on Amazon.com. *FREE* shipping on qualifying offers. World-renowned .": {"and": 4, "World-renowned ": 1, "Robert": 4, "ship": 3, "[": 4, "*FREE*": 2, "Gener": 4, "Albert": 4, ",": 4, ".": 1, "Theori": 4, "rel": 2, "Amazon.com": 4, ":": 3, "qualifi": 5, "offer": 5, "W": 3, "The": 3, "]": 2, "on": 4, "lawson": 2, "Einstein": 4, "Special": 4}, "Special Relativity is a featured book on Wikibooks because it contains substantial  content, it is well-formatted, and the Wikibooks community has decided to .": {"a": 4, "well-format": 4, "and": 2, "featur": 4, "Wikibook": 3, "substanti": 4, "commun": 3, "is": 3, "becaus": 1, "it": 3, "content": 4, "to ": 4, "decid": 3, "book": 4, "Rel": 3, "contain": 3, "the": 3, "ha": 3, ".": 2, ",": 1, "special": 3}, "Relativity (Routledge Classics) and over 2 million other books are available for .  Start reading Relativity (Routledge Classics) on your Kindle in under a minute.": {"and": 1, "over": 2, "are": 2, "Rel": 5, "in": 6, "your": 6, "for": 4, ")": 5, "(": 5, "Routledg": 6, ".": 1, "avail": 3, "start": 2, "book": 2, "rel": 2, "under": 6, "Kindl": 6, "read": 5, "million": 3, "2": 3, "a": 7, "on": 4, "Classic": 6, "minut": 7, "other": 2}, "Braxton welcomes Seven to the Federation timeship Relativity. They explain to  Seven that Voyager has just exploded due to a saboteur putting a temporal .": {"explod": 5, "a": 5, "Seven": 5, "braxton": 2, "just": 5, "that": 4, "temporal ": 5, "explain": 3, "they": 3, "due": 4, ".": 2, "Feder": 5, "to": 5, "Voyag": 5, "saboteur": 6, "Rel": 5, "put": 4, "timeship": 5, "the": 5, "ha": 3, "welcom": 4}, "5 days ago . Relativity Media news that is up-to-the-minute. Get breaking Relativity Media  information and an unfiltered, no-holds-barred analysis of .": {"ago": 2, "and": 3, "of ": 3, "Rel": 4, "that": 5, "no-holds-bar": 3, "Media": 4, "is": 5, "get": 2, ",": 3, "up-to-the-minut": 6, ".": 1, "break": 2, "inform": 3, "analysi": 3, "5": 2, "rel": 2, "unfilt": 3, "news": 4, "an": 3, "day": 2}, "E-Print Archive \"gr-qc\" in which many articles about general relativity and related  topics are published (in advance of publication in conventional journals).": {"and": 5, "topic": 5, "are": 5, "in": 8, ".": 1, "E-Print": 2, "convent": 9, "journal": 9, "(": 3, "publish": 6, "articl": 6, "rel": 7, "public": 8, "``": 1, "which": 5, "advanc": 6, "gener": 7, "relat": 5, "''": 2, "about": 6, "of": 6, "gr-qc": 2, ")": 3, "Archiv": 2, "mani": 6}, "Relativity: Einstein&#39;s theory of special relativity in multimedia tutorial. The  introductory level takes 10 minutes, but has links to over 40 explanatory pages  giving .": {"the": 3, "over": 8, "giving ": 4, "in": 3, "special": 5, "multimedia": 4, ",": 1, "40": 8, ".": 2, "to": 6, "take": 3, "rel": 5, "Einstein&#": 2, ";": 1, ":": 1, "explanatori": 8, "but": 2, "link": 5, "theori": 4, "ha": 3, "introductori": 3, "10": 4, "39": 2, "level": 3, "of": 4, "s": 4, "tutori": 4, "minut": 4, "page": 8}, "Comprehensive online book about special and general relativity, from the  fundamentals to cosmological applications, including a number of philosophical .": {"and": 4, "applic": 7, "about": 3, "from": 3, "philosophical ": 8, "of": 7, "gener": 4, ",": 4, "number": 7, "to": 6, "a": 7, "book": 3, "includ": 5, "rel": 4, "fundament": 6, "comprehens": 3, "onlin": 3, "the": 6, ".": 4, "cosmolog": 7, "special": 4}, "Various pages with non-technical texts about cosmology, black holes, cosmic  strings, inflation, quantum cosmology, and string theory, written by members of  the .": {"and": 2, "text": 5, "the ": 7, "quantum": 3, ",": 2, ".": 2, "member": 6, "written": 3, "black": 3, "string": 3, "variou": 3, "inflat": 3, "non-techn": 5, "theori": 3, "hole": 3, "with": 4, "by": 4, "about": 4, "of": 6, "cosmic": 3, "page": 3, "cosmolog": 3}, "RELATIVITY LAUNCHES NEW FASHION DIVISION  M3/RELATIVITY .  Relativity and Reel FX Round Out Flock on Free Birds Eddie &#39;Piolin&#39; Sotelo,  Danny .": {"and": 3, "Sotelo": 2, "FX": 3, "DIVIS": 5, "REL": 2, "NEW": 4, "Bird": 5, "Piolin&#": 2, "FASHION": 4, ",": 2, "Free": 5, ".": 1, "rel": 3, ";": 1, "Reel": 3, "M3/REL": 5, "Round": 3, "on": 4, "39": 2, "LAUNCH": 4, "Eddie&#": 2, "Danny ": 3, "Flock": 3, "Out": 3}, "relativity, wide-ranging physical theories formed by the German-born physicist  Albert Einstein. With his theories of special relativity (1905) and general relativity  .": {"and": 2, "German-born": 5, "1905": 4, "special": 5, " ": 3, "wide-rang": 2, ")": 3, "(": 3, "Albert": 2, ",": 1, ".": 2, "rel": 3, "form": 3, "gener": 3, "physicist": 5, "hi": 4, "theori": 4, "with": 1, "by": 4, "physic": 3, "of": 4, "Einstein": 2, "the": 5}, ". Sachdev, Jackie English and Bogdan Luca. This page requires a high-speed  connection and Flash Player 6  Contact the authors: relativity(at)onestick(dot) com.": {"and": 2, "onestick": 4, "rel": 4, "high-spe": 4, "Flash": 3, "connect": 4, "Contact": 3, "Luca": 2, "English": 2, "Sachdev": 2, "requir": 3, "a": 4, ":": 3, "author": 3, ")": 3, "(": 3, ",": 2, ".": 2, "Player": 3, "thi": 3, "6": 3, "at": 3, "the": 3, "Bogdan": 2, "com": 3, "page": 3, "dot": 4, "Jacki": 2}}
```

Comment: PHP version? Relevant code?

Comment: @MaximeLorant It shouldnt be, thats the string retrieved from the php script, and its fine as string. The decoding doesnt work and i have no access in that its a library function "json_decode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy-pasted your bit of JSON and it works with `PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:24:35)`.

```
<?php
// This doesnt't work. Putting it here just in case you ran into the same thing.
// It doesn't manage to convert the decoded object into a string.
// echo json_decode(file_get_contents("a.json"));

// This works.
print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents("a.json")));
?>
```

How I tested: http://pastebin.com/Ck7YdQ0y

Comment: Thnx :). It might be the php version then.. Do you know any online place where i can send strings to be json decoded.

Comment: You can also try http://ideone.com/ and see if it works with their version. By the way, are you using that JSON string as a literal in PHP? If yes, make sure it's quoted properly.

Comment: No solution, apparently that version of php cant handle json with string indexes. I had to save as raw text, and use regex to recreate the array >:(